# Session_start and end in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I am building a website. In this website, when a user logged in successfully, how i start session for him and when he hit on log out button ,how i close the session.

Please help me. I am a beginner in Asp.net. So please help me with your answers in Details.

Thank You.

Comment: You need to demonstrate a minimal understanding of how to do what you're trying to do. Then you can come to us with specific questions. Most of your question can be answered simply by doing a web search for relevant tutorials.

Comment: First a user successfully logged in to the application. And he do all kind of work with in the application and logged out from it. In between how application identify each user uniquely.

Comment: You just want the username? From any page code behind you can do `string username=User.Identity.Name;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VB.NET

To Create

> Session.Add("UserSession", MySession)

To Asign

> Dim vUserSession As String = Session.Item("UserSession")

To Close

> Session.Item("UserSession") = Nothing

C#

Check this link there is a good explain

http://forums.asp.net/t/1261964.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you're setting this up, there are .NET controls that provide this functionality mostly for free (you don't have to write a lot of code to get it to work). Look into the Login control.

You need to decide whether you're authenticating against a domain or a database. Most likely it's a database. Just mask sure you hash the password in the database, and hash the password in the app, and compare the hashes.